# How to pass id of an element to a js function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using  tag, and I want to pass its id to function when users clicks on it, I am doing code in onclick event.

following is my html code;

```
<a class="color_2" id="1" onclick="ConfirmDelete()">Delete</a>
```

here I want to pass this is to ConfirmDelete() function.

Comment: ID is invalid, it cannot start with a number

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's [valid in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: @Mr.Alien HTML 5 [removes this restriction](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: you should use Id="id1". ids cannot start with numbers

Comment: @Phylogenesis doesn't mean other languages accept it as valid

Comment: Okay I'll use `id=id1`

Comment: @Mr.Alien That doesn't really make sense; the language doesn't have anything to do with it. It should just implement the DOM as per the specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just type `onclick="ConfirmDelete(this.id)` and it will be sent to your function.

and in function definition;

```
function ConfirmDelete(var_id)
{    
    alert (var_id);
}
```

Comment: That said, it's probably better to use `onclick="ConfirmDelete(this)"` and refer to `this.id` inside the function as this allows future changes to be made more easily.

Comment: Huh?  Question asked and answered by same person at the same time?  How does that work?

Comment: @zipzit Answer your own question?

Comment: Is that like, "I'll use stackoverflow, to create a blog entry.  If I ask the question and immediately answer it, stackoverflow will be a nice repository to remind me of issues I've had and fixed.  It may well help others who experience the problem in the future."  ??  Is this one of those?

Comment: @zipzit: Yes, basically.